# Will a FULLTEXT index on a join column fast the query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, join, full-text-indexing

I am new to this fulltext index and what I know is that the fulltext is used to index text or varchar columns to fast searches.

I have also read that fulltext indexes are used only with (MATCH...AGAINST) synthax? Is that true?

My question was: if I use a fulltext index on a column, will it fast the query or not?

The query is:

SELECT *
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b
ON a.text = b.text;

fulltext index is set for column text for both tables.

Thanks.

Best Regards,

Comment: You can define fulltext index on InnoDb tables having text column . It can speed up queries and DML operations on data contained within those columns, omitting any words that are defined as stopwords.   You can find a performance review here : https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/07/31/innodb-full-text-search-in-mysql-5-6-part-3/

Answer (score 0):

First part of your question about using fulltext index is answered here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html

> Full-text searching is performed using MATCH() ... AGAINST syntax.

Second part is about inner join of two tables based on fields with fulltext indexes. It can be solved with adding into table table1 and table2 fields **texthash**. It's necessary to fill and maintain this hash value (by application code or mysql triggers). 
You can use for this field usual btree index and your sql-query will be modified to version below and performed quickly :

```
SELECT * FROM table1 a INNER JOIN table2 b ON a.texthash = b.texthash;
```